# Comparacion de variables de twig en if

Tags: php, twig, drupal7, drupal8

Me encuentro migrando una web de drupal 7 a 8 en el transcurso de la traduccion de platillas php a lenguaje twig, en una comparacion logica tengo una variable llamada content[field_tipo][0] el cual almacena el tipo de la pagina, si saco esta varialbe por pantalla me devuelve un 5 pero al compararla con 5 , '5' o "5" no devuelve true incluso haciendo un casting a numerico de la variable, mi pregunta es ¿Es algun tipo de objeto o campo de una entidad cierto? en tal caso se conoce algun tipo de casting para convertirlo a string, ademas comentar que en php funcionaba comparando con un numerico

```html
{%if ...%}
{%elseif ...%}
{%elseif content['field_tipo'][0] == 5 %}
            {%if video%}
                <div class="tipo1">
            {%else%}
                    <div class="tipo2">
            {%endif%}
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="">
                                <h3>{{content['field_'][0]}}</h3>   
                                <h1>{{title}}</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="">
                                <h4>{{content['field_'][0]}}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="">
                                <h4>{{content['body']}}</h4>
                            </div>
                            </div>                  
                    </div>--><!-- fin #box_tipo -->
        {%else%}
            <h1>{{content['field_tipo'][0]}}</h1><!--entro aqui y displayeo 5-->
        {%endif%}
```

Comment: Cómo le pasas la variable de vista a twig? A mí no me da ningún problema poniendo `$viewVars = ['content'=>['field_tipo' => [5]]];` y luego `echo $app->view->render('ejemplo.twig', $viewVars);`. Dependiendo del framework, si este implementa una respuesta PSR-7 dentro de una ruta, sería $app->view->render($response, 'ejemplo.twig', $viewVars);` o bien `echo $app->view->fetch(...)`. En ambos casos funciona sin problema. En todo caso, yo compararía `content.field_tipo[0]` porque twig acepta las llaves de un array asociativo usando un punto, como javascript. ¿Es `content` un objeto o un array?

Comment: Tras indagar un poco puedo vislumbrar que es una entidad de tipo nodo lo que tiene content, tampoco puedo debugar en paginas de nodo ya que aparece la web completamente en blanco y sin errores en el log asi que no sabria al 100% pero al tener todos los campos de un nodo debera ser entidad ya que no hay ningun preproceso que pase todos estos argumetnos, y el metodo usado para obtener este campo es algo que aun intento averiguar, esta web fue desarrollada por un tercero ahora ajeno a la empresa.
Gracias

Comment: En ese caso, tendrías que ocupar un serializador (ej: JMS Serializer) para castear el nodo a un array asociativo. Posiblemente twig pueda coercionar una propiedad de nodo a un valor, pero no obtenerlo directamente...  A lo mejor te serviría usar `{% set valor=content['field_tipo'][0] %}` y luego `{% if valor == 5 %}`

Comment: Tras intentar castearla y serializarla por medio de un filtro custom de Twig solo obtenia resultados raros, hasta que probe un filtro que devolvia el tipo, al parecer era un array con un nivel mas del mostrado, y al llamarlo en twig renderiza solo, es decir mostraba el contenido del array sin acceder a el, pero mostrar(renderiza) no es comprar en twig, finalmente por la migracion se habia generado un nuevo nivel (['#markup']) accediendo a el en la comparación no da problema en el if, Gracias a todos